# Binary Search in Sorted Set

Tags: java, set, binary-search, sortedset

I have a `TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();`

I fill the set with some Values:
`set.add(i); // i=1,5,7,44,9,7`
Since it is a sorted Set, I should be able to have the set as follows.
`1 - 5 - 7 - 9 - 44`

now I want to know the position of `9` in the set, which is `3` in this case.

1) I could do a linar search, iterating over the set, increasing a value, it the current element is not equal to the element Im searching for,

2) I could do a Binery Recursive search, determining the length, splitting the set in two, getting the last element of the first subset, determining then, in which subset I proceed the search, and so on.

Is there a cheaper method to search the index of a value in the set?

Comment: Hey Joel, there was already a question asked on this topic... please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911621/how-to-find-the-index-of-an-element-in-a-treeset. This will help you to get the right solution

Comment: A binary search is **O(log n)** while a linear search is **O(n)**.

Comment: @dsh that makes no sense. O(n/2) is the same thing as O(n). A binary search is O(log n)

Comment: The base of that log is 2, maybe that's the source of confusion @dsh?

Comment: @JBNizet my mistake; I thought I should look it up instead of trying to recall

Comment: TreeSet doesn't have indecies but it does a O(log N) search already.  You don't need to do anything, it is written for you.